# Python BDD Behave allure reports failing with format=allure_behave.formatter:AllureFormatter is unknown

Tags: python, bdd, allure, python-behave

I have installed allure 2.8.17. It is on a `pipenv` environment. When I am running the below command  in terminal:

```
behave -f allure_behave.formatter:AllureFormatter -o reports/
```

It is failing with the below error

```
usage: behave [options] [ [DIR|FILE|FILE:LINE] ]+
behave: error: format=allure_behave.formatter:AllureFormatter is unknown
(behave) sharathkrishnan@sharaths-mbp features %
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing allure-behave:
`pip install allure-behave` ?

Comment: Actually I am having behave 2.8.17, it is installed

Comment: @SharathKrishnan you need to install allure-behave not just allure

Comment: Perfect @bluelabel... Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you need to install using pip install allure-behave and then run the above command

Answer (score 0):

This also commonly happens when you point the file path with a typo.
Mostly case sensitive problems like ./Reports instead of ./reports